# Vercel production build returning 405 status code for POST and GET

Tags: reactjs, backend, mern, vercel, http-status-code-405

I am trying to build a website for an online experiment at the university. For this purpose, I was introduced to the MERN stack a couple of months ago and I have more or less finished the website **locally**. Now, whenever I switch to the production build via Vercel, the backend connection to my database is throwing a **405 error**.

Using the [official documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/languages/mern-stack-tutorial) on a previous build I was able to initiate the same connection but any browser other than Chrome would not let me fetch the data. So I changed the entire backend to [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/iamshaunjp/MERN-Stack-Tutorial) from a YouTube tutorial. Once again the solution worked perfectly fine on the development builds but failed in production. After some debugging I saw the problem was in the **.post(URL)** I am passing (in /src/Pages/Home1.js):

```
import axios from "axios";

(...)
    axios
      .post("/api/participants", passvalue)
      .then(() => {
        console.log("new participant added with AXIOS");
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log("Unable to add with AXIOS: ", e);
      });
(...)
```

On local builds, the complete URL is `http://localhost:5001/api/participants` where the PORT 5001 is defined in my **.env** file. This URL should by default create a **GET** request and list all dummy mongodb entries according to my **Routes** (/server/routes/participants.js):

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const {
  createParticipant,
  getParticipants,
  getParticipant,
  updateParticipant,
} = require("../controllers/participantController");

router.get("/", getParticipants);

router.get("/:id", getParticipant);

router.post("/", createParticipant);

router.patch("/:id", updateParticipant);

module.exports = router;
```

Since both **GET** and **POST** work locally but not in production the problem is understanding why `https://watchortype.vercel.app/api/participants` (**watchortype** being the Vercel project name) returns an empty page and throws the 405 error in production.

I went over MERN stack tutorials which work fine locally but did not work in production. I expected (i) to see a MongoDB entry to be created when I run the **POST** command and (ii) to see **GET** command showing a JSON list of all dummy database entries as Postman locally does.

Instead I get this in console.log() for **POST**:

```
{
    "message": "Request failed with status code 405",
    "name": "AxiosError",
    "stack": "AxiosError: Request failed with status code 405\n    at https://watchortype.vercel.app/static/js/main.204f7c46.js:2:538227\n    at XMLHttpRequest.f (https://watchortype.vercel.app/static/js/main.204f7c46.js:2:538375)",
    "config": {
        "transitional": {
            "silentJSONParsing": true,
            "forcedJSONParsing": true,
            "clarifyTimeoutError": false
        },
        "adapter": [
            "xhr",
            "http"
        ],
        "transformRequest": [
            null
        ],
        "transformResponse": [
            null
        ],
        "timeout": 0,
        "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
        "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
        "maxContentLength": -1,
        "maxBodyLength": -1,
        "env": {},
        "headers": {
            "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "method": "post",
        "url": "/api/participants",
        "data": "{\"attention1\":\"0\",\"attention2\":\"0\",\"treatment\":\"autoplayOn\",\"lottery\":\"lotteryLose\",\"platform\":{\"type\":\"desktop\",\"vendor\":\"Apple\"},\"browser\":{\"name\":\"Chrome\",\"version\":\"107.0.0.0\"},\"ID\":\"brave testa\",\"clikcedOkToSwitch\":\"not yet\",\"timeChoice\":0,\"leisureTime\":0,\"laborTime\":0,\"transcription\":{}}"
    },
    "code": "ERR_BAD_REQUEST",
    "status": 405
}
```

and for **GET** -essentially a blank page saying :

```
You need to enable JavaScript to run this app
```

```
<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"/><link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico"/><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/><meta name="theme-color" content="#000000"/><meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app"/><link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/logo192.png"/><link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json"/><title>React App</title><script defer="defer" src="/static/js/main.204f7c46.js"></script><link href="/static/css/main.2c68cbb0.css" rel="stylesheet"></head><body><noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript><div id="root"></div></body></html>
```

How do make Vercel production connect to my database? What is the missing link between deployment and production builds with regards to the backend configuration?